# Does openai GPT finetuning consider the prompt in the loss function?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, gpt-2

OpenAI api includes a finetuning service that divides the task in "prompt" and "completion"

https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning

The documentation says that the accuracy metrics are calculated respect to the completion. But for the loss it is said that it is calculated "on the training batch".

My understanding is that the first training of a GPT model always happen in batches of max available size, using an special token to separate contexts but always asking to predict the next token for all the entries. So here the loss function is the obvious cross entropy over all the outputs. But in fine tuning, there is the opportunity to learn to predict the "template prompt" or not. Both decisions can be sensible; learning the template amounts to train a parsing, masking the template can avoid overfitting.

So, what is the current practice in OpenAI?

Answer (score 2):

Open AI API has a parameter `prompt_loss_weight` whose default is 0.01, as compared to the completion which always has a weight of 1.0. So yes, it considers the prediction of the prompt as part of the loss function.

This usage seems different to fine-tuning tutorials with other tools as Huggingface transformers library, that allow for a mask to discard part of the output but does not consider different weight of the losses.